# Proof of $\text{det} \begin{bmatrix} A &B\\ 0&C\\ \end{bmatrix}=\text{det}(A)\cdot \text{det}(C)$ in Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, determinant

> Suppose we have an $n \times n$ matrix of the block form $\begin{bmatrix} A &B\\ 0&C\\ \end{bmatrix}$ where $A$ is an $r\times r$ matrix, $C$ is an $s\times s$ matrix, $B$ is $r\times s$, and $0$ denotes the $s\times r$ zero matrix. Then $$\text{det} \begin{bmatrix} A &B\\ 0&C\\ \end{bmatrix}=\text{det}(A)\cdot \text{det}(C).$$ To prove this, define $$D(A,B,C)=\text{det} \begin{bmatrix} A &B\\ 0&C\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
> If we fix $A$ and $B$, then $D$ is alternating and $s$-linear as a function of the rows of $C$. Thus, by theorem 2 section 5.3 $$D(A,B,C)=\text{det}(C)\cdot D(A,B,I)$$
> where $I$ is the $s\times s$ identity matrix. By subtracting multiples of the rows of $I$ from the rows of $B$ and using the fact, if $B$ is obtained from $A$ by adding a multiple of one row of $A$ to another, then $\text{det}(B)=\text{det}(A)$, we obtain $$D(A,B,I)=D(A,0,I)$$
> Now $D(A, 0,I)$ is clearly alternating and $r$-linear as a function of the rows of $A$. Thus $$D(A,0,I)=\text{det}(A)\cdot D(I,0,I).$$
> But $D(I,0,I)=1$, so $$\begin{align*} D(A,B,C)&=\text{det}(C)\cdot D(A,B,I)\\ &= \text{det}(C)\cdot D(A,0,I)\\ &= \text{det}(C)\cdot \text{det}(A)\end{align*}$$

IMO, proof skip lots of detail. **(1)** If we fix $A$ and $B$, then $D$ is alternating and $s$-linear as a function of the rows of $C$. Proving alternating is easy. Let $C\in M_s(K)$ with rows $\alpha_1,…,\alpha_s$ such that $\alpha_i=\alpha_j$, for some $i\lt j$. Since $r+i$th and $r+j$th row of $\begin{bmatrix} A &B\\ 0&C\\ \end{bmatrix}$ are equal, we have $D(A,B,C)=\text{det} \begin{bmatrix} A &B\\ 0&C\\ \end{bmatrix}=0$. Hence $D$ is alternating as a function of the rows of $C$. **Que:** How to show $D$ is $s$-linear as a function of the rows of $C$?

**(2)** By subtracting multiples of the rows of $I$ from the rows of $B$ and using the fact, if $Q$ is obtained from $P$ by adding a multiple of one row of $P$ to another, then $\text{det}(Q)=\text{det}(P)$, we obtain $D(A,B,I)=D(A,0,I)$. **Que:** I don’t understand this step.

**(3)** But $D(I,0,I)=1$. **Que:** How to prove it?

---

**Edit:** Following answer is by @Joe. **(1)** Since $[0\dotsb 0\ c\alpha_i]=c[0\dotsb 0\ \alpha_i]$, we have $D(A,B,c\alpha_i)=cD(A,B,\alpha_i)$. Since $[0\dotsb 0\ \alpha_i+\alpha_i’]=[0\dotsb 0\ \alpha_i]+[0\dotsb 0\ \alpha_i’]$, we have $D(A,B,\alpha_i+\alpha_i’)=D(A,B,\alpha_i)+D(A,B,\alpha_i’)$. Hence $D$ is $s$-linear as a function of the rows of $C$.

**(2)** $D(A,B,I)=D(A,0,I)$ because $D$ is defined in terms of the det function, and the block matrix with blocks $A$, $0$, and $I$ can be attained from the block matrix with blocks $A$, $B$, and $I$ by adding multiples of the last $s$ rows to the first $m$ rows, which does not change the determinant, since the determinant is multi-linear in the rows.

**(3)** $D(I,0,I)$ is the determinant of the $(r+s) \times (r+s)$ identity matrix.

Comment: For your first question, I suspect that the author is using the fact (I assume shown earlier in the text), that the determinant of a matrix is multi-linear in the rows.  Do you want to know how to prove that?  Or are you asking why that implies that $D(A,B,C)$ is $s$-linear in the rows of $C$?  The latter is just because of how $D$ is defined using the $\mathrm{det}$ function.

Comment: For you second question, again $D(A,B,I)=D(A,0,I)$ because $D$ is defined in terms of the $\mathrm{det}$ function, and the block matrix with blocks $A$, $0$, and $I$ can be attained from the block matrix with blocks $A$, $B$, and $I$ by adding multiples of the last $s$ rows to the first $m$ rows, which does not change the determinant, since the determinant is multi-linear in the rows.  Does that answer that question?  If not, are you asking how to show that the $\mathrm{det}$ has this property of not being affected by adding multiples of one row to another?

Comment: For your last question, $D(I,0,I)$ is the determinant of the $(m+s) \times (m+s)$ identity matrix.

Comment: @Joe Thank you for the comment. Since $[0\dotsb 0\ c\alpha_i]=c[0\dotsb 0\ \alpha_i]$, we have $D(A,B,c\alpha_i)=cD(A,B,\alpha_i)$. Since $[0\dotsb 0\ \alpha_i+\alpha_i’]=[0\dotsb 0\ \alpha_i]+[0\dotsb 0\ \alpha_i’]$, we have $D(A,B,\alpha_i+\alpha_i’)=D(A,B,\alpha_i)+D(A,B,\alpha_i’)$. I was trying to prove both case simultaneously and I got confused. I knew proof of it can’t be complicated, I must have done some step wrong. Now I know what I did wrong. Your second comment answer my second question.

Comment: @Joe If I understand correctly, we have to do $r\times s$ times such operation (subtracting scalar multiple of $r+j$th row of $\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\ 0&I\\ \end{bmatrix}$ to $i$th row, where $1\leq j\leq s$ and $1\leq i\leq r$) to get $\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\ 0&I\\ \end{bmatrix}$. After reading your answer, I will say Hoffman’s rephrasing was extremely poor and vague. Your third comment answer my third question. It is so simple. In my head, I was thinking $I$ as matrix with all entries $1$. Which is absolutely stupid. That’s why I sometimes write identity matrix as $I_n$, $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't supposed to be an answer.  I was commenting from my cell phone, and must have accidentally posted it as an answer.

Comment: I also find the author's wording confusing.

Comment: Nothing stupid about thinking $I$ was a matrix of all ones.  Each particular math notation, although helpful when you're fluent in it, can also be a source of a lot of confusion.

Comment: @Joe Thank you for the answer. I will edit my question to include my first comment and your second & third comment. Is that ok for you?

Comment: It would be better to post an answer to your own question.  You can use anything that was helpful from my comments in your answer.